# I have a networking problem in UDP's connect()

Tags: c, linux, unix, network-programming

I write this as an exercise, and I think UDP connect will throw datagrams whose source IP is not the same as what we connect() before, but the results are not what I expected.

I want to ask why my server can't receive a message from my client, thanks.

And I get a ICMP message. [image]

(172.28.33.22 is my other IP address)

```c
#include <unp.h>

int main()
{
    int cfd;
    struct sockaddr_in bind_addr, addr;

    if ((cfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
        err_sys("socket");

    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(10000);
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr) == -1)
        err_sys("inet_pton");

    bzero(&bind_addr, sizeof(bind_addr));
    bind_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bind_addr.sin_port = htons(40000);
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "172.28.33.22", &bind_addr.sin_addr) == -1)
        err_sys("inet_pton");
    if (bind(cfd, (struct sockaddr *)&bind_addr, sizeof(bind_addr)) == -1)
        err_sys("bind");

    if (sendto(cfd, "a", 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 1)
        err_sys("sendto");

    return 0;
}
```

```c
#include <unp.h>

int main()
{
    int sfd, readn;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    struct sockaddr_in conn_addr;
    char data[MAXLINE];

    if ((sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
        err_sys("socket");

    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(10000);
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "0.0.0.0", &addr.sin_addr) == -1)
        err_sys("inet_pton");
    if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
        err_sys("bind");

    bzero(&conn_addr, sizeof(conn_addr));
    conn_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    conn_addr.sin_port = htons(40000);
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "172.28.33.22", &conn_addr.sin_addr) == -1)
        err_sys("inet_pton");
    if (connect(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&conn_addr, sizeof(conn_addr)) == -1)
        err_sys("connect");

    if ((readn = read(sfd, data, MAXLINE)) < 0)
        err_sys("read");
    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, data, readn) != readn)
        err_sys("write");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Binding on a specific port is usually a bad idea when you use `connect`. But before attempting this, make sure that you can actually perform network activity. It could well be that the problem is in the firewall configuration. Your question is very brief. I would need to read way more of what *doesn't* work and what *does* work, before I would spend time on troubleshooting network programming.

Comment: Have you tried tcpdump `-i any` flag to listen on all interfaces, not sure if traffic will show only on localhost.